# How to find out allowed options for the Clojure-function (spit)?

Tags: java, clojure, documentation

The Clojure-function `spit` allows to write data into files, e.g.:

```
(spit "filename.txt" "content")
```

It also allows to add content to existing files.

```
(spit "filename.txt" "content" :append true)
```

In the documentation (`(doc spit)`) it only says that options can be passed to the `clojure.java.io/writer`. But `(doc clojure.java.io/writer)` does not list allowed options. So is there a "detailed-mode" for documentation available?

I found the `:append`-option via http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/spit , but I'm sure it is also listed somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: Check [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html).

Answer (score 2):

Probably most of the options are mapped from Java underlying libraries

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

By browsing the source code I confirm that `:encoding` is legal

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/java/io.clj#L74-L77

```
Common options include

 :append    true to open stream in append mode
 :encoding  string name of encoding to use, e.g. \"UTF-8\".
```

I cannot help further as Java isn't my more frequently used language, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

via `clojure.java.io/writer` to `make-writer`, so found it in [io.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/41af6b24dd5be8bd62dc2b463bc53b55e18cd1e5/src/clj/clojure/java/io.clj);

```
(defprotocol ^{:added "1.2"} IOFactory
  "Factory functions that create ready-to-use, buffered versions of
  the various Java I/O stream types, on top of anything that can
  be unequivocally converted to the requested kind of stream.
  Common options include

   :append    true to open stream in append mode
   :encoding  string name of encoding to use, e.g. \"UTF-8\".
  Callers should generally prefer the higher level API provided by
  reader, writer, input-stream, and output-stream."
  (^{:added "1.2"} make-reader [x opts] "Creates a BufferedReader. See also IOFactory docs.")
  (^{:added "1.2"} make-writer [x opts] "Creates a BufferedWriter. See also IOFactory docs.")
  (^{:added "1.2"} make-input-stream [x opts] "Creates a BufferedInputStream. See also IOFactory docs.")
  (^{:added "1.2"} make-output-stream [x opts] "Creates a BufferedOutputStream. See also IOFactory docs."))
```

@Edward, there are just `:append` and `:encoding`

@Jaime Agudo's answer is right, I'd not saw his answer :-(.